# nagios core external agent using python scripting

Tags: python, nagios

I have a bash script for performing the passive checks i.e., external agent/application. I tried converting the bash script into python but when I execute the file I don't see any kind of responses on my nagios core interface regarding my passive check result.

```
import os
import datetime

CommandFile='/usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd'
datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
os.stat(CommandFile)
f = open(CommandFile, 'w')
f.write("/bin/echo " + str(datetime) + " PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT;compute-1;python dummy;0;I am dummy python")
f.close()
```

my bash script code is:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Write a command to the Nagios command file to cause
# it to process a service check result

echocmd="/bin/echo"

CommandFile="/usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd"

# get the current date/time in seconds since UNIX epoch
datetime=`date +%s`

# create the command line to add to the command file
cmdline="[$datetime] PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT;host-name;dummy bash;0;I am dummy bash"

# append the command to the end of the command file
`$echocmd $cmdline >> $CommandFile`
```

Comment: Please share your bash script for comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have updated my post.

Comment: I think you want to open the file for append and not write.

Comment: Yes Sir, but when I try to append, it throws me an error saying "Error: 29: Illegal seek"

Comment: 1) Restore the original nagios.cmd file with proper permissions and ownership. Maybe with a nagios server restart? Since it got overwritten I wouldn't trust the permissions are correct. 2) Add the newline character '\n' at the end (inside) of the cmdline string.

Comment: I tried restarting it but still it doesn't show any change in the nagios interface. here are the steps I followed 1)Added '\n' at the end of the f.write("") 2) systemctl restart nagios.service 3) executed the pythonscript.py

Answer (score 0):

Changed my code, now its working perfectly fine. I can see the response in the Nagios interface.

```
import time
import sys

HOSTNAME = "compute-1"

service = "python dummy"

return_code = "0"

text = "python dummy is working .....I am python dummy"

timestamp = int(time.time())

nagios_cmd = open("/usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd", "w")

nagios_cmd.write("[{timestamp}] PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT;{hostname};{service};{return_code};{text}\n".format

                    (timestamp = timestamp,

                     hostname = HOSTNAME,

                     service = service,

                     return_code = return_code,

                     text = text))


nagios_cmd.close()
```